# How to split string by HEX character

Tags: vbscript, split

I need help to split string which contains a HEX character.
How to do it?
The code I have got doesnt work.

```
dim itr 
itr="343434 XX7777777" '  SI
msgbox itr
dim scrns
scrns=Split(itr,"SI",-1,1)
msgbox scrns(1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the character by its numeric value (0x0f for "shift in"):

```
scrns = Split(itr, Chr(&h0f))
```

In VBScript you define hexadecimal numbers by prefixing them with `&h`. The [`Chr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws6aa3sf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function turns the number into the corresponding character.

As @JNevill pointed out in the comments you could also use the decimal instead of the hexadecimal value:

```
scrns = Split(itr, Chr(15))
```

Comment: I believe "Shift in" is also just ascii character 15, so `screns = Split(itr, Chr(15))` (15 in decimal being 0f in hex) should work equally well.